# Adding to variables in Batch?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I was wondering if it's possible to add something to a variable in batch.

Say I was making a program that every time you hit one, the variable went up, but every time you hit 2, it went down.

Comment: could you share some code what you are doing. It is not possible to help you like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /a total=0
:loop
ECHO total is %total%
choice /c 12q /M "1 or 2; Q to quit"
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO :EOF 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET /a total-=1&GOTO loop
SET /a total+=1&GOTO loop
GOTO :EOF
```

1 for up, 2 for down. See `choice /?` or `set /?` from the prompt for driving instructions.